# SQL query remembering certain results, regardless of database itself

Tags: postgresql, next.js, next.js13

I'm using Next/Postgres to build a project, and I ran into this problem.

```ts
//api/fetchPostList/route.ts
import { sql, db } from "@vercel/postgres";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
    try {
        const postListQuery = await sql`SELECT id, title FROM posts;`;
        const postList = postListQuery.rows;
        return NextResponse.json({data: postList}, { status: 200 });
    }
    catch(e){
        return NextResponse.json({data: null}, {status: 500});
    }   
}
```

This is my route function, and I'm changing the SQL part.

| title | content | author | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First Post! | first post uploaded | qdrptd | 1 |
| Second Post! | second post uploaded | qdrptd | 2 |
| Third Post! | third post uploaded | dtprdq | 3 |
| Fourth Post! | fourth post uploaded | dtprdq | 4 |
| Fifth Post! | fifth post uploaded | qdrptd | 5 |

This is my database, and I get the result

```js
{ id: 1, title: 'First Post!' },
{ id: 2, title: 'Second Post!' },
{ id: 3, title: 'Third Post!' },
{ id: 4, title: 'Fourth Post!' },
{ id: 5, title: 'Fifth Post' },
```

This is okay, but after I insert another post, and my database becomes like this.

| title | content | author | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First Post! | first post uploaded | qdrptd | 1 |
| Second Post! | second post uploaded | qdrptd | 2 |
| Third Post! | third post uploaded | dtprdq | 3 |
| Fourth Post! | fourth post uploaded | dtprdq | 4 |
| Fifth Post! | fifth post uploaded | qdrptd | 5 |
| Another post... | Another post uploaded | qdrptd | 6 |

But the query still returns the same result below.

```js
{ id: 1, title: 'First Post!' },
{ id: 2, title: 'Second Post!' },
{ id: 3, title: 'Third Post!' },
{ id: 4, title: 'Fourth Post!' },
{ id: 5, title: 'Fifth Post' },
```

Btw, if I change the query into something else, such as

```SQL
SELECT id, content FROM posts;
```

I get the right result, but after inserting another document, the same problem occur again.

I've never seen any bugs like this, I hope anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

Next automatically caches the results of your requests in some cases, in order to increase response speed and lower the load on the server (read more about Next caching [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating). Caching means that the result of a request is stored and reused for a certain length of time, rather than running the code again. This can be helpful sometimes but it sounds like you don't want that here.

POST requests are not cached, and there are a variety of ways to disable caching on the server side (the link above lists them, and depending on your use case some might make more sense than others). You can also use `fetch('https://...', { cache: 'no-store' })` when sending a request to retrieve up-to-date data from the database.

Comment: Wow that was the problem! It worked..!! You saved me!!